# Does the order of SAS drive matter when installing old drives?

Tags: hard-drive, sas, raid1, ibm-xseries

I have an old IBM server with 12 hard drive bays, 4 of which are used (SAS 72GB drives), and configured in a RAID 1 array. The server will be sent away for repairs, when it comes back, do I need to reassemble the drives in the same bays they were taken out?

Comment: I found out that some SCSI Controllers will remember the configuration for the removed drives and set the drives up correctly. Check with your server manufacturer to be certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Please try to keep the drives in the same positions. Label them before you send the server away.